# C++ integer type twice the width of a given type

Tags: c++, c++11, std

In this example, `coord_squared_t` is the alias for an integer type with at least twice the size of the integer type `coord_t`:

```
typedef int_least32_t coord_t;

coord_squared_t CalculateSquaredHypothenuse(coord_t x, coord_t y){
    coord_squared_t _x=x;
    coord_squared_t _y=y;
    return _x*_x+_y*_y;
}
```

What could be used to express `coord_squared_t` in terms of `coord_t`?  Is there anything in the standard library that allows me to do something like `double_width<coord_t>::type` to get the correct width, instead of explicitly choosing the type?

C++11 or C++14 are fine.

Comment: Why not use fixed with types like `int32_t` and `int64_t`?

Comment: You can map the fixed width integers explicitly ... nothing fancy, I admit

Comment: I could, but according to the reference `int8_t`, `int16_t` and friends are optional, only `int_leastN_t` is guaranteed to be present.  Writing conditionals for the four integer types is a solution, but I was hoping for something neater.

Comment: Out of scope :are you sure that double_width is enough ?

Comment: double_width is enough, apart from `-2^31`.  Unless coord_t is an unsigned integer type.

Comment: This is addressed by proposal [P0381](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0381r0.html). `using coord_squared_t = set_width_t<coord_t, width<coord_t>::value * 2>;`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use [`boost::int_t`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/integer/doc/html/boost_integer/integer.html#boost_integer.integer.synopsis):

```
using coord_squared_t = boost::int_t<sizeof(coord_t)*CHAR_BIT*2>::least;
```

Comment: Looks like what I want, but it's boost...  I'll mark this as accepted if there are no other answers.

Comment: @Bernard What's wrong with boost? It is even header-only part of it.

Comment: Nothing really wrong with boost; I haven't written enough C++ to need to use boost. I think I'll be using this in my code.

Comment: @Bernard Boost is kind of a high-quality provider of those missing parts of standard library that we all need. I think you will enjoy Boost :)

Comment: TIL, updating some projects now to remove the handwritten specializations

Comment: you may consider using 8->CHAR_BIT

Comment: @RiaD Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 13):

If you don't want to use Boost, you could just implement this manually with some specializations:

```
template <class > struct next_size;
template <class T> using next_size_t = typename next_size<T>::type;
template <class T> struct tag { using type = T; };

template <> struct next_size<int_least8_t>  : tag<int_least16_t> { };
template <> struct next_size<int_least16_t> : tag<int_least32_t> { };
template <> struct next_size<int_least32_t> : tag<int_least64_t> { };
template <> struct next_size<int_least64_t> : tag<???> { };

// + others if you want the other int types
```

And then:

```
using coord_squared_t = next_size_t<coord_t>;
```

---

Alternatively you can specialize based on number of bits:

```
template <size_t N> struct by_size : by_size<N+1> { };
template <size_t N> using by_size_t = typename by_size<N>::type;
template <class T> struct tag { using type = T; };

template <> struct by_size<8>  : tag<int_least8_t> { };
template <> struct by_size<16> : tag<int_least16_t> { };
template <> struct by_size<32> : tag<int_least32_t> { };
template <> struct by_size<64> : tag<int_least64_t> { };
```

This way, something like `by_size<45>::type` is `int_least64_t` due to inheritance. And then this becomes just like the Boost answer:

```
using coord_squared_t = by_size_t<2 * CHAR_BIT * sizeof(coord_t)>;
```

Comment: This'll probably work everywhere the questioner really cares about, but he expresses concern that `intN_t` are optional. So it's also optional whether or not `int_least64_t` is at least twice as big as `int_least32_t`. They might both be the same type, even (let's say both 64 bits), in which case `next_size_t<int_least32_t>` is *not* double the width of `int_least32_t`. Ofc it's still big enough to contain the result of multiplying two values that don't exceed 2^31 in magnitude, so if you control what you put into `coord_t` then you're fine.

Comment: @SteveJessop The requirement isn't that `sizeof(next_size_t<X>) == 2 * sizeof(X)`. The requirement is that `next_size_t<X>` is able to hold the next larger amount of bits.

Comment: The problem is that the template can’t tell whether a 16-bit type was actually because the caller uses 16 bits, or if it was the *least* size available when he only needed 8. The size of the domain he plans on using may be smaller than the actual type, but that’s what the decision should be based on.

Comment: @Barry: well, the questioner *says* they want a type with at least double the width of a given type. `int_least64_t` is *not* guaranteed to have at least double the width of `int_least32_t`. It's just guaranteed to have width at least double the lower bound on the width of `int_least32_t`. It's entirely possible the questioner is wrong about their requirements, and you're right that this is sufficient. I just thought it worth pointing out that you have changed the requirements.

Comment: So in particular, with this code on some funny architecture you could end up with `next_size_t<int>` is `int`, whereas `long long` would have been double the size of `int`. That would surprise someone (including the questioner) who comes in thinking "I want a type that's double the width of `int` so that I can use it to multiply `int` without overflow" and trying to use this answer.

Comment: Mind you there is some protection: the most likely practical reason for that funny architecture to exist now or in the immediate future, is because there's no integer types smaller than 64 bits, and all of `least16_t`, `least32_t`, `least64_t` are the same type. In which case the code lets you know with an error that you've defined the same specialization more than once, and you can fix it for that platform :-)